# Can you pipeline from an FTP retrieving multiple files?

Tags: bash, fasta, ncbi

I’m trying to retrieve hundreds of genomes from NCBI and pipe them to the server Phaster (directly or through my local server).
Can you pipe the output of an FTP retrieving multiple files in one command?
I’ve tried using rsync and wget.

Any FTPs that work well in pipelines?

Comment: Can you share the commands that you use to retrieve the file (or a short shell/bash script) ? It will help SO readers to give you advice, based on the work you already did

Comment: Could you be more specific about your need. Looks like you want to download a bunch of files from an ftp server. You could use wget `wget --user=username --password=123 ftp://ftp.place.to.downloadfrom.com/path2files`

Comment: U could try `ncftp`! But for working with pipelines (see `coproc` in [tag:bash]), you'll better use flat simple `ftp` client.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I have file with the contents below.

> Kluyveromyces_lactis
> ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/002/515/GCF_000002515.2_ASM251v1
> latest_Complete Genome_Major Leishmania_major_strain_Friedlin
> ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/002/725/GCF_000002725.2_ASM272v2
> latest_Complete Genome_Major Plasmodium_falciparum_3D7
> ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/002/765/GCF_000002765.5_GCA_000002765
> latest_Complete Genome_Major Caenorhabditis_elegans
> ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/002/985/GCF_000002985.6_WBcel235
> latest_Complete Genome_Major Bacillus_pseudofirmus_OF4
> ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/005/825/GCF_000005825.2_ASM582v2
> latest_Complete Genome_Major Escherichia_coli_str._K-12_substr._MG1655
> ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/005/845/GCF_000005845.2_ASM584v2
> latest_Complete Genome_Major Methanococcus_voltae_A3
> ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCF/000/006/175/GCF_000006175.1_ASM617v2
> latest_Complete Genome_Major

And, if I want to download Kluyveromyces_lactis .fna and .gtf file, I run php code below

```
<?php
$process=new GDownloading("assembly_summary_refseq_new.txt","ftp_links_of_species_1.txt", "Chromosome");
//$process->Sorting();
$process->Download();

class GDownloading
{
    public $s_file, $r_file, $g_opt;
    function __construct($SourceFile, $ResultFile, $Goption)
    {
        $this->s_file=$SourceFile;
        $this->r_file=$ResultFile;
        $this->g_opt=$Goption;
    }
    function Sorting()
    {
        $gfile = fopen($this->s_file, "r");
        $resfile = fopen($this->r_file, "wb");
        while($line=fgets($gfile, 1000000))
        {
            if($line[0]=="#")
            {continue;}
            $pts = explode("\t", $line);
            if (substr($pts[19], 0, 4) == "ftp:")
            {
                if ($pts[10]=="latest" && $pts[11]==$this->g_opt && $pts[12]=="Minor")
                {
                    $ftp_link = $pts[19];
                    $sp_name = str_replace(" ", "_", $pts[7]);
                    fwrite($resfile, "$sp_name\t$ftp_link\t$pts[10]_$pts[11]_$pts[12]\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($gfile);
        fclose($resfile);
    }
    function Download()
    {
        $ftp_link = fopen($this->r_file, "r");
        if(!is_dir("Chromosome"))
        {
            mkdir("Chromosome");
        }
        $download_count=0;
        while($line=fgets($ftp_link, 10000))
        {
            $dir=scandir("Chromosome");
            $pts=explode("\t", $line);
            $pts[0]=str_replace("/", "", $pts[0]);
            $pts[0]=str_replace(":","_", $pts[0]);
            if(in_array("$pts[0]", $dir))
            {
                $folder_name=$pts[0] . "_" . $download_count;
            }
            else
            {
                $folder_name = $pts[0];
            }
            $link = $pts[1];
            mkdir("Chromosome/$folder_name") ;
            $file=explode("/", $link);
            $file=end($file);
            $fna=$link."/".$file."_genomic.fna.gz";
            $gtf=$link."/".$file."_genomic.gtf.gz";
            system("wget -c ".$fna." -P Chromosome/".$folder_name);
            system("wget -c ".$gtf." -P Chromosome/".$folder_name);
            $download_count++;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please format your answer so that it could be readable.

Comment: Excuse me, what did you mean by word "format"? I can add some //comments to my code page only. Did you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

The python package [GenET](https://github.com/Goosang-Yu/genet) database module provides functions to easily download frequently used data files from NCBI.
For example, to download the genomic assembly of `Homo sapiens`, you can use `GetGenome` as follows:

```py
from genet.database import GetGenome
```

To create a GetGenome instance for the desired species:

```py
# Specify the species
species = "Homo sapiens"

# Create a GetGenome instance
genome = GetGenome(species)
```

To check the available files related to the assembly of the specified species:

```py
# Check available files
available_files = genome.contents()
print("Available files:", available_files)
```

> Available files:
> ['README.txt',
> 'Annotation_comparison',
> 'GCF_000001405.40_GRCh38.p14_assembly_structure',
> 'GCF_000001405.40-RS_2023_10_annotation_report.xml',
> 'annotation_hashes.txt',
> 'RefSeq_transcripts_alignments',
> 'GCF_000001405.40_GRCh38.p14_assembly_regions.txt',
> ...]

To download the desired file with the specified name to the desired path:

```py
# Specify the desired file name
file_name = "example_genome.fasta"

# Specify the desired download path
download_path = "/desired/download/path/"

# Download the file
genome.download(file_name, download_path)
```